# Using PHP to get the last inserted customer email

Tags: magento-enterprise, php, mysql, customer-account

I have a script that loads Customers/Addresses into Magento, but sometimes it fails.
I would like to pick up were I left of (I am transforming data from one DB to Magento).
What is a cheap way to get the last inserted customers email?

```
SELECT email FROM customer_entity ORDER BY entity_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is that a safe/sane way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get last inserted customer id by magento customer collection filter by entity_id desc

**Step1:** `Load customer collection with sort by entity descending and by using setpagesize limt collection limit 1`

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc')->setPageSize(1);

    /* get ;last customer $object by  $lastcst */
```

**step2:** `get customer object getFirstItem(); which will provide fist item collection`

```
$lastcst=$collection->getFirstItem();
```

**Step3:** `get customer email`

```
$lastcst->getEmail();
```