# Magento 2 - Last inserted customer

Tags: magento2, customer, query

Using models how would I get the last inserted customer, even if that customer was inserted 6 days ago?

Would the best bet to get customers and order by date created and limit it to 1 result?

Answer (score 1):

You can get *last inserted customer id by magento customer collection filter* by **entity_id desc**

> **Step1**: Load customer collection with sort by entity descending and by
> using setpagesize limt collection limit 1
> Blockquote
>
> **Step2**: get customer object `getFirstItem();` which will provide fist
> item collection
> Blockquote
>
> **Step3**: get customer data

If you need code sample then I can provide you...

For reference lets have a look at the [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/36514/49732)